# How do I apply a numpy mask?

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have two input arrays `a1` and `a2`:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([1,2,3])
a2 = np.array([4,5,6])
```

I am trying to mask `a1` and get this output array based on the values in `a2`; i.e. (not) equal to 5:

```
array([999999, 2, 999999])
```

Why is this method not correct?

```
np.ma.array(a1, mask=np.ma.masked_equal(a2, 5)).filled()
```

It (in)correctly returns:

```
array([999999, 999999, 999999])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(a2==5,a1,999999)
array([999999,      2, 999999])
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a handy line of code. I thought the op is looking for a deeper understanding of masked arrays. But in practice I'd choose your solution over mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```py
np.ma.array(a1, mask=a2!=5).filled()
```

to get the desired result `[999999 2 999999]`.

Or do you really need to use `np.ma.masked_equal`? If so, you probably want to look into the opposite `np.ma.masked_not_equal`, since this is what you want to mask out.